# Setting Taxonomy Terms in a View Loop in Drupal Rules Module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-rules

**Relevant Modules:** Rules (and dependents), Views (and dependents), VBO, Views Rules

**Scenario:**
When adding a new node of type "Team", I would like Rules to loop through all current "Leagues" (Taxonomy) and create a duplicate team for each, setting a field of the node to the Looping "League".  In this way, dding one team will result in multiple teams, each one with a field set to a Different League.

**Current Setup:**
Drupal 7.23, all modules current.  I have the View setup to return a list of Taxonomy Terms (See Resource #2) and a Rule set up so multiple copies of each Team are created upon save. (See Resource #1)

**Problem:** I cannot get Views to return the taxonomy terms in a format that will allow me to set a field of that content type.  If it returns a rendered Taxonomy Entity, Rules throws an error, and if the View returns "Taxonomy Term: Names", Rules does not allow the values to be used to set Taxonomy Fields (data-type miss-match?).

**Question:** What settings will cause Views to return a Taxonomy list in an ... "Entity" ... format so that it can be used to set Taxonomy Term Reference fields within Rules?

**Resources:**

Current Rules Config: http://psofe.com/pic/view/?q=rules_view (Screenshot)

Current Views Config: http://psofe.com/pic/view/?q=view_setup (Screenshot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it -- the settings were under: Views --> The View --> Rules Settings --> Row Variables (Set datatype here).

Needed to feed Rules the Entity Id, and fetch the entity from the Rules side.